# two model properties in single textboxfor in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show two properties concatenated in single textbox.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name+m.Lanme)
```

Can I do that?

Comment: I think you cannott bind multiple model properties to a single template item

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this logic in your Controller and have a property called `FullName`.

For example:

```
ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
model.Person = GetPerson();
model.FullName = model.Person.FirstName + " " + model.Person.LastName;
return View(model);
```

Then simply do:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.FullName)
```

---

If you wanted to take it a step further, `FullName` could be a property of `Person` and carry out the logic in `GetPerson()` method.

Comment: ok.. thank you... but we cannot do that without adding new property.. right?

Comment: @hetalgala Thats correct you would need to add a new property to your View Model